# NSFetchedResultController won't show data in IOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-data, ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am new to IOS development. At the moment I'm building an iPad app, what gets data back from the webservice, saves it in a core database and shows it in a tableview using NSFetchedResultController.

What is the problem. In IOS6 it al works like a charm, in IOS 5.0 it saves the data but not showing it in the tableview. It gives the following error.

```
 CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  The NIB data is invalid. with userInfo (null)
```

And when I test in IOS 5.1 it does not do anything. It does not shows data in a tableview and data is not being stored in core database.

Here is what I do. In my view did appear I check if there is a document I can use.

```
if (!self.genkDatabase) {  // we'll create a default database if none is set
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default appGenk Database"];
        self.genkDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url]; // setter will create this for us on disk
    }
```

Then it goes to my setter. And next in usedocument gonna check in which state my document is.

```
- (void)setGenkDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)genkDatabase
{
    if (_genkDatabase != genkDatabase) {
        _genkDatabase = genkDatabase;
        [self useDocument];
    }
    NSLog(@"Comes in the setdatabase methode.");
}

    - (void)useDocument
    {
        NSLog(@"Comses in the use document");
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.genkDatabase.fileURL path]]) {
            // does not exist on disk, so create it
            [self.genkDatabase saveToURL:self.genkDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                NSLog(@"create");
                [self setupFetchedResultsController];
                NSLog(@"create 2");
                [self fetchNewsIntoDocument:self.genkDatabase];
                NSLog(@"create 3");
            }];
        } else if (self.genkDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
            NSLog(@"closed news");
            // exists on disk, but we need to open it
            [self.genkDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                [self setupFetchedResultsController];
            }];
        } else if (self.genkDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
            NSLog(@"normal");
            // already open and ready to use
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        }

    }
```

Finally I fetch my data in my document using the following function.

```
- (void)fetchNewsIntoDocument:(UIManagedDocument *)document
{
    dispatch_queue_t fetchNews = dispatch_queue_create("news fetcher", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchNews, ^{
        NSArray *news           = [GenkData getNews];
        [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        int newsId          = 0;
        for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in news) {
            newsId++;
            [News newsWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext withNewsId:newsId];
            NSLog(@"news inserted");
        }
        [document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
        }];

    });
    dispatch_release(fetchNews);
}
```

For the problem in IOS 5.0 is this my NSFetchResultController method.

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController // attaches an NSFetchRequest to this UITableViewController
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"News"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES],nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                managedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                cacheName:nil];
}
```

I am doing this like the example from Paul Hegarty in stanford university. You can find the example *Photomania* over [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Photomania_0.zip).

Hope anyone can help me!

Kind regards

Comment: Just an idea: Is "Use Autolayout" switched off in the File inspector of your XIB files? Autolayout works only on iOS 6.

Comment: @MartinR I switched off Autolayout on every xib and also storyboard. but still getting the error. Any other ideas ?